# getting null reference in create view

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I have created a method in the Employee controller for creating a new Employee:

```
        [HttpGet]
        [ActionName ("Create")]
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

I have Added a view for Create method with Employee(strongly-typed)model and used the **create** template.
When I run the program and click on create new I get a null reference error in create view.

```
@model BuissnessLayer.Employee

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Employee</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Employee_Id, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Employee_Id, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Employee_Id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Employee_Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Employee_Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Employee_Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Employee_Age, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Employee_Age, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Employee_Age, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Employee_City, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Employee_City, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Employee_City, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Employee_Salary, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Employee_Salary, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Employee_Salary, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

I get the error at line

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Employee_Id, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

I don't know how to solve the problem because the code is created automatically and i haven't edited anything yet.

Comment: It may not be the reason you're seeing the exception, but are you sure you don't want an `HttpPost` in your controller instead of an `HttpGet`?

Comment: You need to pass your model in to `return View();`

Comment: @melancia  i have both methods httpget and httppost seperately with same action name.

Comment: What do you expect `model.Employee_Id` to be when no model is passed in (i.e. `model` is `null`)?

Comment: @phuzi thanks it worked. i was following a tutorial from youtube(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qpAe45xTEfQ) and he didn't pass model name in his code but his code worked .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass model to your View..

```
[HttpGet]
[ActionName ("Create")]
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var model = new Employee(){}
    return View(model);
}
```

@model BuissnessLayer.Employee

Comment: Thank you it worked. i had created instance of employee and passed it into view is it bad to do it this way?